# Is it possible to upgrade JUST the tomcat embedded in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have another question here,

WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 runs on top of Apache Tomcat/7.0.14. This version of tomcat has found many security vulnarabilties ( http://tomcat.apache.org/security-7.html)

I am trying to see if we can upgrade the tomcat version in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 to latest in 7.* version?

If yes how can I cleanly do that?

It is big company and they would love to have secure WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 implementation with Data Services they love.

thanks again for help.
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

No, I think you can't upgrade the tomcat version of wso2esb 4.0.3. If you inevitably needed the upgraded version, use wso2esb 4.7.0 which has the latest version of tomcat.